# How to increase audio loading speed using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, android, html, html5-audio

I have created code for playing an `.mp3` file using JavaScript. But the file is taking to much time to play on Android. I want to play the sound quickly after click on a text image. How do I increase loading speed on Android?

My JavaScript code:

```
if(window.audio) 
{
    audio.pause(); 
}
window.audio = new Audio (audio_path);
window.audio.play();
```

Check demo here -
http://97.74.195.122/gizmo-demo/canvasslidertwo.php

In the above link, click on the Japanese word for playing sound.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cloning audio source without having to download it again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30433667/cloning-audio-source-without-having-to-download-it-again)

Answer (score 3):

You are actually facing the bug depicted in **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30433667/3702797)**. Which makes chrome browsers redownload the files from an Audio Element each time you change its src property (no-caching).

One solution would be to use the `WebAudioAPI`and store your audio files in the buffer. Doing so, you should be able to call them with no latency.
You can check [the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30440830/3702797) for an example on how to deal with it.

Or you could also try not to call a new Audio() on each click, and rather load every audios from your page and only call their `play()` method on click.
But I'm not sure it would fix your issue.

Comment: When I click on text-image, I want to play sound quickly. Now Its taking time to play sound.

Comment: You mean it takes time to load it?